How to deal with large files in PS
So I was making a design for a backdrop which has the size of 10ft x 17ft (120inx204in) And I am having a problem because the file is tooooo large that even my pc is unresponsive.
I saw a tip that says to create smaller preset of the same ratio and design there. May I ask if how do I exactly convert it to a smaller preset? (how do I find the same ratio)
And any advice about working with larger files in photoshop?

See What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?

It's basic math.
Assuming final output requires 10'x17' @ 300ppi....

50% is 5'x8.5' (divide by 2)
25% is 2.5'x4.25' (divide by 4)

Just remember to multiply the PPI by the same factor.

5'x8.5' needs to be 600ppi (multiply by 2)
2.5'x4.25' needs to be 1200ppi (multiply by 4)


Most large-format printing may not require 300ppi. See here:
What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?
